# Conditional If Empty Statement

Tags: if-statement, filemaker, calculation

Sorry for the noob question. I have built a system where the agent must take customers details, such as first name, last name, email add, number etc & the system requires that all fields be filled out before they can proceed, I have achieved this just fine.

The problem I'm having is with the telephone numbers. There are 2 fields for this "Telephone" & "Mobile"

I need to make it so that the agent can proceed if "one or the other" is filled out. So if they had a Mobile but not a Telephone number (or vice versa) that would be fine and the agent could proceed.

How can I achieve this? Sorry again for the amateur question.

Comment: "*I have achieved this just fine*" You're not telling us *how* you achieved this - which makes it difficult to discuss changes to what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Require:

```
not IsEmpty ( Telephone ) or not IsEmpty ( Mobile )
```